# Paypal buy it now form not working

Tags: html, paypal

The code below causes Paypal to give me this error:
 **PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.**

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="JLALRRNUV8LPW">
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Art:">Art:</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
        <option value="1">1 $0.00 USD</option>
        <option value="2">2 $0.00 USD</option>
        <option value="3">3 $0.00 USD</option>
        <option value="4">4 $0.00 USD</option>
        <option value="5">5 $0.00 USD</option>
    </select> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Choose a Scalemate">Choose a Scalemate</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
        <option value="Senator Lemonsnout">Senator Lemonsnout </option>
        <option value="Professor Pucefoot">Professor Pucefoot </option>
        <option value="Inspector Berrybreath">Inspector Berrybreath </option>
        <option value="Doctor Honeytongue">Doctor Honeytongue </option>
        <option value="Duke Pinesnort">Duke Pinesnort </option>
        <option value="Pyralspite Plush">Pyralspite Plush </option>
        <option value="Liaison Pumpkinsnuffle">Liaison Pumpkinsnuffle </option>
    </select> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Username">Username</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

I've been through the code countless times and I'm lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the amount for all the drop down as "0.00" as in

```
<option value="1">1 $0.00 USD</option>
    <option value="2">2 $0.00 USD</option>
    <option value="3">3 $0.00 USD</option>
    <option value="4">4 $0.00 USD</option>
    <option value="5">5 $0.00 USD</option>
```

You need to edit your button code in the PayPal account to change the amount to more than "0.00" and it should be fine after that .